# MySQL connection string without sensitive information

Tags: mysql

I'm making a WPF application and I use MySQL so I want to publish the application so I need to change the connection string so it wont contain any sensitive information like the password and the user name.

How can I do that?

And if you have any tips for me before publishing the application to make it more secure it will be great :D

Comment: what is a WPF application?

Comment: WPF ( Windows Presentation Foundation ) basicly are .NET programming languages @luksch

Comment: Don't include MySQL connection string within a application.. With a disassembler is really easy to find MySQL connection string within a Windows application.

Comment: Its very hard to give a useful answer without more context. In general, you would have some kind of configuration mechanism where you can put the sensitive information in an external config file or environment variables.

Comment: How can I do it without MySQL? @RaymondNijland

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface my answer by saying I'm not 100% sure if WPF deals with Environment Variables.

What I would do is store the username/password and MySQL Server in environment variables. By doing it that way you're not exposing those parameters inside your codebase, which will help not compromising your credentials.

Once that's done, make sure to add some information about it in the Readme.md (or whatever markdown you're using) so that other people know that they need those environment variables for it to work.

Comment: Can I have an example on how to do that?

Comment: For windows, this article goes into how creating an Environment Variable: https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500

And how to extract them using VB.NET is detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx